# Tengo problemas al actualizar el composer a un antiguo proyecto

Tags: php, angular, symfony, composer

Hace unos días, descargue un antiguo proyecto de una plataforma desarrollada en el Framwork de PHP Symfony como backend y Angular como Frontend.
Resulta que hasta entonces he tenido un poquito de problemas, porque la versión de composer de ese proyecto ya es un poquito atrasada, ya que estamos hablando de un proyecto que se programo a comienzo de 2017.

Resulta que para poder correr el programa sin problemas, necesito actualizar el composer del proyecto. Con la consola de comando en la carpeta de synfony del proyecto ejecute el comando: `composer update`, resulta que comenzo a actulizarse, pero ya al final me lanzo unos mensajes que no se si sea una advertencia o si sea un mensaje de error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Apague mi servidor local de **Xampp** y luego volví a encenderlo, pero el proyecto seguía con el error que ahora mismo les muestro en pantalla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito saber si se actualizo el composer de mi proyecto o si hubo algún tipo de error, y si hubo un error como solucionarlo.

La versión actual de mi composer es la *1.9.1*, no se exactamente cual es la versión del composer de mi proyecto y no se si hubo éxito cuando lance el comando `composer update` para actualizar la versión de composer de mi proyecto, en fin es que los errores siguen en el proyecto

Si necesitan mas informacion, por favor haganmelo saber, mientras tantos yo les dejo el archivo *composer.json*

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.7",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^3.0.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.5.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.5.9"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

si usas el `composer update` va actualizar los paquetes y al ser un versión del framework quizás haya paquetes que no son compatibles. Intenta usar el `composer install` para  bajar las dependencias de acuerdo a como lo tiene en el composer.json. Quizas deba borrar la carpeta `vendor` y  el archivo `composer.lock`

Comment: Me sale este error: `[RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command:






    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]

    Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you me
  an
     to use "continue 2"?

`

Comment: Hice todo comu usted dijo, y incluso elimine hasta la cache pero salen estos errores: `Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handl
ing the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception
`

Comment: Estos fueron los 3 errores: `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean
   to use "continue 2"?
`